# Is it guaranteed that handler for wpf view event is called in UI-thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, events

If I write handler of wpf event can I be sure that it will be executed in UI-thread and don't use additional checks? What specification does describe this case? . I belevie that handler is called in UI-thread but I haven't any proofs

Comment: You could easily write a view element with an event that is fired in a background thread. If that would make sense is a different question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that handler for wpf view event is called in UI-thread

Yes, unless you create a background thread somewhere and raise the event from this one somehow. And to clarify, UI thread here means that thread on which the control that raised the event was originally created. You *can* actually create controls on different UI threads than the default one. But none of the built-in UI controls raises their events on a background thread by default.

So if you don't create any controls on any background threads, the UI events will always be raised on the main dispatcher thread.